# Assigning user to Azure Active Directory enterprise application via python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

I have added slack to Azure Active Directory Enterprise application and running SSO. I want to assign users and groups to the app in azure. So, basically, it is really easy to use portal. Also , I provided the PowerShell script as well.

```
#AzureAD Module
#Azure login : Connect-AzureAD
$app_name ="slack"
$app_role_name = "user"

$user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "$username"
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
```

now, I have to do same task with python, I found the Azure Python SDK, but I am not sure which library I should use? any body has any experience to support me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve it - meaning there is no direct object/module that can help you achieve your requirement AFAIK.

The below is the index of all the SDK for python, skimming through this i don't see any libs that can be used to achieve your requirement

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-library-package-index#all-libraries

Having said that, the other approach I can think is making use of the Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0

You can issue the request  to the mentioned endpoint from the Python.